# Adobe Flex datagrid's renderer validation

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have got a advanced datagrid with around 20 rows out of which only 7 are visible (vertical scroll in ON). I am using item renderer on one column with rendererAsEditor=true.

I am doing user side validation for all these renderers. Now if I don't scroll down even once, the renderers for hidden rows would not be created. So, when I click submit, validation for rows's that were not created will not happen.

Is there a way by which I can validate hidden rows as well?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by validation? Can you post some code?

Comment: I am not allowed to post the code here :(

I want to do user end validation. For example, if there is a text input in the renderer. So on focus out/submit click, I want to do required validation for that text input field.

My problem is if that textinput as a renderer is not yet created (as it is not visible yet on grid), then how can I validate it using Validator

Comment: If the renderer was never created there either is no data to validate or the data may have been entered in previously (where it would have been validated). Guess I'm missing something Herr?

Comment: I would use different component for this like list or datagroup.